# win32com.client.Dispatch неверно передает путь

Tags: python, winapi

Не могу понять в чем дело...

```
import win32com.client
path = r'F:\1.Сертификаты ГОССТРУКТУР\Ардатовский муниципальный округ\Жданкин.cer'

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
shell.SendKeys(path)
```

Вставляет такую запись - а:\1.Сертификаты ГОССТРУКТУР\Ардатовский муниципальный округ\Жданкин.35

Иногда такую - F:\1. `00\  \00  .cer`

Переписывал строку под эту, нужного эффекта нет...

```
shell.SendKeys(path.encode("utf-8"))
```

В чем причина не пойму, в интернете даже примерной темы не нашел. Помогите пожалуйста, нужно что бы выдало - F:\1.Сертификаты ГОССТРУКТУР\Ардатовский муниципальный округ\Жданкин.cer

Comment: Если английская раскладка, то `F:\1. \`00\  \00.cer` иначе `а:\1.Сертификаты ГОССТРУКТУР\Ардатовский муниципальный округ\Жданкин.35` добавьте переключение раскладки на нужную

Comment: `def setCyrillicLayout():
    window_handle = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    result = win32api.SendMessage(window_handle, 0x0050, 0, 0x04190419)
    return(result)

def setEngLayout():
    window_handle = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
    result = win32api.SendMessage(window_handle, 0x0050, 0, 0x04090409)
    return(result)` делал на русскую и на английскую, перед тем как SendKeys, но ни чего не дало... источник где нашел код https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-beginners/thread1685571.html

Comment: @МихаилШиршов не перед SendKeys. У вас буква диска должна вводиться в английской раскладке, а вся остальная часть в русской. Т.е. переключение должно быть посредине. Чтобы универсально было, нужно вообще разбирать где буквы в какой раскладке должны быть. Если в GUI окно текст передается, то возможно проще через WinAPI SendMessage с WM_SETTEXT просто текст установить.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо большое. Напишите пожалуйста Ваш ответ, я его приму. Сам принцип стал понятен))) но сделал я немного по другому) сделал директорию нечто похожую на "F:\gos\21\ser.cer", где 21 это номер района и отправляет вроде нормально, если заранее поставить вручную раскладку английскую и использовать функцию setEngLayout() одновременно, в предыдущем комменте. На первое время сойдет, переделаю... (работа не ждет...)